# attributes not hiding unavailable product options on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute

I switched from an old magento version ( 1.9.0.1) to the latest stable release (1.9.2.4) and suddenly discovered that the new version has a lot of issue with product attributes.
I've managed to solve the attribute ordering, but now seems that I have another strange behaviour .

---

If I have more than a single attribute used for a configurable product it doesn't work correctly 
It doesn't force the customer to select a choice in the first required option , and it doesn't exclude ( hide) products that don't have the corresponding attribute value .

 Ex : I have a configurable product (T-Shirt) with 2 attributes with dropdown menu.

1st is color 

2nd is size.

Attributes are set correctly.

Both are requested to purchase the product

I have made an attribute set for this specific products.

Attribute order is set correctly on configurable product page

If I have in stock 3 "XL" in brown color and 1 "M" in green color ,Magento should display ONLY the "M" option for the "SIZE" if I choose the green color on the first dropdown option, and not all the option related to the other attribute .
Also, it should hide even the products that are out of stock....
It looks like if the standard Magento filtering process for attributes is not working anymore , and if I go on with the purchase I get a popup message stating "the quantity is not available".

I'm not much of an expert, so I don't know where to look to find where is the problem.

I've spent 2 days searching on the web , but nothing helped me.

Comment: i have the same problem, and same results ... nothing helped and seems that no one have this problem ... have you solved it ? thank you

Comment: i have he same issue too, have you managed to solve it? i need a solution as soon as possible, thank you !!!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/65129)

Answer (score 0):

Check if template product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml is customized and compare it with standard template.
Probably the spConfig remained to an older version.